# Pivoting table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query, pivot, unpivot

I was wondering if it is possible to change the output of this:

```
User           Database            Select  Insert  Update  Delete  Create  References  Alter   Drop    
-------------  ------------------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ----------  ------  --------
mysql.session  performance_schema  1       0       0       0       0       0           0       0       
mysql.sys      sys                 0       0       0       0       0       0           0       0
```

into this:

```
Users               Privileges      performance_schema      sys
-----               ----------      ------------------      ---
mysql.session       Select                  1       
mysql.session       Insert                  0       
mysql.session       Update                  0       
mysql.session       Delete                  0       
mysql.session       Create                  0       
mysql.session       References              0       
mysql.session       Alter                   0       
mysql.session       Drop                    0       
mysql.sys           Select                                  0
mysql.sys           Insert                                  0
mysql.sys           Update                                  0
mysql.sys           Delete                                  0
mysql.sys           Create                                  0
mysql.sys           References                              0
mysql.sys           Alter                                   0
mysql.sys           Drop                                    0
```

The query I used is this:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT
  USER "User",
  db "Database",
  IF(Select_priv = 'Y', '1 ', '0') AS "Select",
  IF(Insert_priv = 'Y', '1 ', '0') AS "Insert",
  IF(Update_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') AS "Update",
  IF(Delete_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') AS "Delete",
  IF(Create_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') AS "Create",
  IF(References_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') AS "References",
  IF(Alter_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') AS "Alter",
  IF(Drop_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') AS "Drop"
 FROM
    mysql.db
 ORDER BY
    USER, Db;
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What's wrong with your query?

Comment: This is unpivotting (backward operation). And I do not see any reason to edit your current query - create new one from the same beginning and use UNION ALL.

Comment: he doesn't want the first table which he already has, he wants the second table as result

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I want the second table as my result.

Comment: @Akina, will you please elaborate?

Comment: @nbk yes exactly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you your result.

If you need the privileges in the same order . you need to add a column to the c (the union table) with then order you want.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
               CONCAT('MAX(IF(s.Database = "', `Database`,'", `data`,"")) AS "',`Database`,'"')
              ) INTO @sql
FROM (select t.user AS Users,
     t.db  "Database",
       c.Privileges,
       case c.col
         when 'Select_priv' then IF(Select_priv = 'Y', '1 ', '0') 
         when 'Insert_priv' then IF(Insert_priv = 'Y', '1 ', '0')
         when 'Update_priv' then IF(Update_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') 
         when 'Delete_priv' then IF(Delete_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') 
         when 'Create_priv' then IF(Create_priv = 'Y', '1 ', '0')
         when 'References_priv' then IF(References_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') 
        when 'Alter_priv' then IF(Alter_priv = 'Y', '1 ', '0')
         when 'Drop_priv' then IF(Drop_priv = 'Y', '1', '0') 
       end as data
     from mysql.db t
     cross join
     (
       select 'Select_priv' as col, 'Select' AS Privileges      
       union all select 'Insert_priv',"Insert"
       union all select 'Update_priv',"Update"
       union all select 'Delete_priv',"Delete"
       union all select 'Create_priv',"Create"
       union all select 'References_priv',"References"
       union all select 'Alter_priv',"Alter"
       union all select 'Drop_priv',"Drop"
     ) c
 ORDER BY
    USER ) table1;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.Users,s.Privileges,  ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM (select t.user AS Users,
     t.db  "Database",
       c.Privileges,
       case c.col
         when "Select_priv" then IF(Select_priv = "Y", "1 ", "0") 
         when "Insert_priv" then IF(Insert_priv = "Y", "1", "0")
         when "Update_priv" then IF(Update_priv = "Y", "1", "0") 
         when "Delete_priv" then IF(Delete_priv = "Y", "1", "0") 
         when "Create_priv" then IF(Create_priv = "Y", "1", "0")
         when "References_priv" then IF(References_priv = "Y", "1", "0") 
        when "Alter_priv" then IF(Alter_priv = "Y", "1", "0")
         when "Drop_priv" then IF(Drop_priv = "Y", "1", "0") 
       end as data
     from mysql.db t
     cross join
     (
       select "Select_priv" as col, "Select" AS Privileges      
       union all select "Insert_priv","Insert"
       union all select "Update_priv","Update"
       union all select "Delete_priv","Delete"
       union all select "Create_priv","Create"
       union all select "References_priv","References"
       union all select "Alter_priv","Alter"
       union all select "Drop_priv","Drop"
     ) c
 ORDER BY
    USER )  s
                 GROUP BY s.Users,s.Privileges
                 ORDER BY s.Users');
#SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated!! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 -- unpivot to get 4 columns -- user, db, priv, value

Step 2 -- pivot to move db into columns.

(Your tentative code is more of a "pivot" on the privs.  So it is not useful for either step.)

I suggest you think about how the end result will look and how useful (or not useful it will be).  And how bulky it will be.

Comment: You are right. It will look quite bulky depending on how many databases the MySQL Server has. But it is a requirement so...